# column that shows the sum() for each category

Tags: sql-server, stored-procedures

I would like a column that shows the sum(AMOUNT) for each category (over 90, over 60, over 30)

```
DECLARE @DATE VARCHAR(10)
SET @DATE='2012-12-31' 
SELECT TRANDATE, TRANTYPE, INVNUM,SUM (AMOUNT), PAID, CLIENTID, 

      (CASE  WHEN TRANDATE <= DATEADD(dd, -90, @DATE) THEN  SUM(AMOUNT) END ) AS 'OVER 90', 
      (CASE  WHEN TRANDATE<DATEADD(dd, -90, @DATE) AND  TRANDATE<=DATEADD(dd, -60, @DATE) THEN SUM(AMOUNT) END) AS 'OVER 60' ,  
      (CASE  WHEN TRANDATE<DATEADD(dd, -60, @DATE) AND  TRANDATE<=DATEADD(dd, -30, @DATE) THEN SUM(AMOUNT) END)AS  'OVER 30' ,
      (CASE  WHEN TRANDATE<DATEADD(dd, -30, @DATE) THEN SUM(AMOUNT) END) AS 'CURRENT'            
from Bill
where  TRANTYPE IN ('INV', 'PAY') AND   TRANDATE<=@DATE AND CLIENTID=7434
GROUP BY TRANDATE, TRANTYPE, INVNUM, PAID, CLIENTID
```

how can i do this. I tried but not get real value.Thanks for your comments and answer .

```
TRANDATE    TRANTYPE   INVNUM  AMOUNT  PAID    CLIENTID  OVER90  OVER60  OVER30
2012-05-06   INV       230496  7803.50 7803.50  7434     7803.50  NULL   NULL
```

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Try this...

```
DECLARE @DATE VARCHAR(10)
SET @DATE='2012-12-31' 
SELECT TRANDATE, TRANTYPE, INVNUM,SUM (AMOUNT), PAID, CLIENTID, 

      SUM((CASE  WHEN TRANDATE <= DATEADD(dd, -90, @DATE) THEN  AMOUNT END )) AS 'OVER 90', 
      SUM((CASE  WHEN TRANDATE>DATEADD(dd, -90, @DATE) AND  TRANDATE<=DATEADD(dd, -60, @DATE) THEN AMOUNT END)) AS 'OVER 60' ,  
      SUM((CASE  WHEN TRANDATE>DATEADD(dd, -60, @DATE) AND  TRANDATE<=DATEADD(dd, -30, @DATE) THEN AMOUNT END))AS  'OVER 30' ,
      SUM((CASE  WHEN TRANDATE>DATEADD(dd, -30, @DATE) THEN AMOUNT END)) AS 'CURRENT'            
from Bill
where  TRANTYPE IN ('INV', 'PAY') AND   TRANDATE<=@DATE AND CLIENTID=7434
GROUP BY TRANDATE, TRANTYPE, INVNUM, PAID, CLIENTID
```

in your code condition for 'CURRENT', 'Over 30' and 'Over 60' are checking for TRANDATE<  which should be TRANDATE>

Comment: @Gautam I have changed the query the condition you are checking in the case statement is wrong, see updated one

Answer (score 0):

Wrap the case statements in a `SUM`:

```
DECLARE @DATE VARCHAR(10)
SET @DATE='2012-12-31' 
SELECT TRANDATE, TRANTYPE, INVNUM,SUM (AMOUNT), PAID, CLIENTID, 
      SUM(CASE  WHEN TRANDATE <= DATEADD(dd, -90, @DATE) THEN  AMOUNT END ) AS 'OVER 90', 
      SUM(CASE  WHEN TRANDATE<DATEADD(dd, -90, @DATE) AND  TRANDATE<=DATEADD(dd, -60, @DATE) THEN AMOUNT END) AS 'OVER 60' ,  
      SUM(CASE  WHEN TRANDATE<DATEADD(dd, -60, @DATE) AND  TRANDATE<=DATEADD(dd, -30, @DATE) THEN AMOUNT END) AS  'OVER 30' ,
      SUM(CASE  WHEN TRANDATE<DATEADD(dd, -30, @DATE) THEN AMOUNT END) AS 'CURRENT'            
from Bill
where  TRANTYPE IN ('INV', 'PAY') AND   TRANDATE<=@DATE AND CLIENTID=7434
GROUP BY TRANDATE, TRANTYPE, INVNUM, PAID, CLIENTID
```

Comment: this value is display value for `OVER 90` `OVER 60` `OVER 30` in every column

Comment: Not sure I follow, please post the results of the query.

Comment: @Goutam check the answer I posted, I does what u are looking for.

Answer (score 0):

write a query with no grouping a CASE statement to get a calculated column in it with values

'over 90', 'over 60', 'over 30' in it as according to the record, name column anything, e.g. MySection

then query and group this query as a derrived query - wrap your sub query giving you all your fields along with age into the main query

, e.g.

```
    SELECT TRANDATE, TRANTYPE, INVNUM,MySection,SUM (AMOUNT), PAID, CLIENTID, 

from ( ... your derived query in here..) AS DQ
where  TRANTYPE IN ('INV', 'PAY') AND   TRANDATE<=@DATE AND CLIENTID=7434
GROUP BY TRANDATE, TRANTYPE, INVNUM, PAID, CLIENTID, MySection
```